# How to solve Long Python expressions?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to programming and am learning Python. I wanna ask the order in which simple arithmetic expressions of python are solved. I mean e.g there is a simple question `10 / 2 * 5 - 2`.

Now, in which order will it be solved? Like first division, then multiplication, then subtraction like in DMAS rule or is there some other rule.

Also, if there is a question, 10 % 5 % 3, I'm confused at these long Modulo expressions, so please help me.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 5):

Expressions are resolved using the documented [operator precedence table](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

This means that multiplication and division comes before subtraction, with operators of equal precedence being applied from left to right, so the expression can be read as:

```
((10 / 2) * 5) - 2
```

The same applies to the modulo operator; the operations are applied from left to right:

```
(10 % 5) % 3
```